# Text manipulation with sed

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed

Currently, I have multiple text files with contents looking like this (with many lines):

```
565 0 10 12 23 18 17 25
564 1 7 12 13 16 18 40 29 15
```

I wish to change each line to have the following format:

```
0 565:10:1 565:12:1 565:23:1 565:18:1 565:17:1 565:25:1
1 564:7:1 564:12:1 564:13:1 564:16:1 564:18:1 564:40:1 564:29:1 564:15:1
```

Are there any way of doing the above using sed? Or do I need to resort to Python?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could do it with sed, yes, but other tools are simpler. For example:

```
$ awk '{
        printf "%s ", $2; 
        for(i=3;i<=NF;i++){
            printf "%s:%s:1 ",$1,$(i) 
        }
        print ""
       }' file 
0 565:10:1 565:12:1 565:23:1 565:18:1 565:17:1 565:25:1 
1 564:7:1 564:12:1 564:13:1 564:16:1 564:18:1 564:40:1 564:29:1 564:15:1
```

#### Explanation

awk will split each line of input on whitespace (by default), saving each fields as `$1`, `$2`, `$N`. So:

- `printf "%s ", $2;` will print the 2nd field and a trailing space.
- `for(i=3;i<=NF;i++){ printf "%s:%s:1 ",$1,$(i) }` : will iterate over fields 3 to the last field (`NF` is the number of fields) and for each of them it will print the 1st field, a `:`, then the current field and a `:1`.
- `print ""` : this just prints a final newline.

Or Perl:

```
$ perl -ane 'print "$F[1] "; print "$F[0]:$_:1 " for @F[2..$#F]; print "\n"' file 
0 565:10:1 565:12:1 565:23:1 565:18:1 565:17:1 565:25:1 
1 564:7:1 564:12:1 564:13:1 564:16:1 564:18:1 564:40:1 564:29:1 564:15:1
```

#### Explanation

The `-a` makes `perl` behave like `awk` and split its input on whitespace. Here, the fields are stored in the array `@F`, meaning that the 1st field will be `$F[0]`, the 2nd `$F[1]` etc. So:

- `print "$F[1] "` : print the 2nd field.
- `print "$F[0]:$_:1 " for @F[2..$#F];` : iterate over fields 3 to the last field (`$#F` is the number of elements in the array `@F`, so `@F[2..$#F]` takes an array slice starting at the 3rd element until the end of the array) and print the 1st field, a `:`, then the current field and a `:1`.
- `print "\n"` : this just prints a final newline.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a <del>horrible</del> `sed` way!

```
$ sed -r 's/^([0-9]+) ([0-9]+) ([0-9]+)/\2 \1:\3:1/; :a s/([0-9]+)(:[0-9]+:1) ([0-9]+)( |$)/\1\2 \1:\3:1 /; t a; s/ $//' file
0 565:10:1 565:12:1 565:23:1 565:18:1 565:17:1 565:25:1 
1 564:7:1 564:12:1 564:13:1 564:16:1 564:18:1 564:40:1 564:29:1 564:15:1
```

More readably:

```
sed -r '
s/^([0-9]+) ([0-9]+) ([0-9]+)/\2 \1:\3:1/
:a 
s/([0-9]+)(:[0-9]+:1) ([0-9]+)( |$)/\1\2 \1:\3:1 /
t a
s/ $//'
```

#### Notes

- `-r` use ERE
- `s/old/new/` replace `old` with `new`
- `^([0-9]+)` save some numbers at the start of the line
- `\1` backreference to first saved pattern
- `:a` label this section of the script `a`
- `( |$)` either a space or the end of the line
- `t` test whether the last replacement was successful - if it was, then do the next command
- `a` find the label `:a` and do it again
- `s/ $//` remove the trailing space

So after adding the structure to the first part, we repeatedly find the last instance of the structure and apply it to the next number...

But I agree other tools make it easier...

Comment: I was waiting for your sed solution :D

Comment: :D it took me a while @Ravexina - I reckon muru can make a cleaner one

Answer (score 5):

With awk:

```
awk '{printf "%s ",$2; for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) printf $1":"$i":1 "; printf "\n"}' file
```

or with bash:

```
while read -r -a a; do                  # read line to array a
  printf "%s " ${a[1]}                  # print column #1
  for ((i=2;i<${#a[@]};i++)); do        # loop from column #2 to number of columns
    printf "%s " "${a[0]}:${a[$i]}:1"   # print content/values
  done
  echo                                  # print line break
done < file                             # read file from stdin
```

Output:

```
0 565:10:1 565:12:1 565:23:1 565:18:1 565:17:1 565:25:1 
1 564:7:1 564:12:1 564:13:1 564:16:1 564:18:1 564:40:1 564:29:1 564:15:1
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, you can do it in sed, but python works also.

```
$ ./reformatfile.py  input.txt                                                                        
0 565:10:1 565:12:1 565:23:1 565:18:1 565:17:1 565:25:1
1 564:7:1 564:12:1 564:13:1 564:16:1 564:18:1 564:40:1 564:29:1 564:15:1
```

Contents of the `reformatfile.py` are as so:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1]) as fd:
    for line in fd:
        words = line.strip().split()
        pref = words[0]
        print(words[1],end=" ")
        new_words = [ ":".join([pref,i,"1"]) for i in words[2:] ]
        print(" ".join(new_words))
```

How does this work? There's really nothing particularly special going on. We open first command-line argument as file for reading and proceed with breaking down each line into "words" or individual items. First words becomes `pref` variable, and we print on stdout second ( words[1] ) item ending with space. Next we construct new set of "words" via list comprehensions and `.join()` function on a temporary list of pref, each word, and string `"1"`. Final step is to print those out

Answer (score 4):

With `awk`:

```
awk '{printf("%s ", $2); for(i=3; i<NF; i++) printf("%s:%s:1 ", $1, $i);\
          printf("%s:%s:1\n", $1, $NF)}' file.txt
```

It's all about formatting space-separated fields in desired format:

- `printf("%s ", $2)` prints the second field with a trailing space
- `for(i=3; i<NF; i++) printf("%s:%s:1 ", $1, $i)` iterates over the 3rd to second last fields and prints the fields in desired format (first field, then a colon, then the current field, then a colon, finally 1) with a trailing space
- `printf("%s:%s:1\n", $1, $NF)` prints the last field with newline

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt
565 0 10 12 23 18 17 25
564 1 7 12 13 16 18 40 29 15

% awk '{printf("%s ", $2); for(i=3; i<NF; i++) printf("%s:%s:1 ", $1, $i); printf("%s:%s:1\n", $1, $NF)}' file.txt
0 565:10:1 565:12:1 565:23:1 565:18:1 565:17:1 565:25:1
1 564:7:1 564:12:1 564:13:1 564:16:1 564:18:1 564:40:1 564:29:1 564:15:1
```